# .htaccess file access

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have a question regarding .htaccess file access for css files and js files

i have this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?page=index [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&subpage=$2 [L,NC]
```

now, i realize some files (like js, css) load correctly without using:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
```

will it be better if I add it before my rules, or it doesnt matter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually it is safe to include `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f` in Rewrite rules so that physical files like css, js, images etc are not affected by these rules.

However in your case **none of your rules will impact these css, js, images files** because you are not including dot character `.` in your matching reular expression.

To overcome your issue I recommend **using absolute path in your css, js, images files** rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Answer (score 0):

`js, css` files will be cached by your browser. 
But in your case, for the path mentioned in the comments & the rewrites mentioned above. it will not affect. But any future rewrite rules may have affect on these. So it is better to add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`.

Comment: but it works without it even after clearing the cache. so is it important to add it?

Comment: @EscoMaji what doe the path to your `js, css` files look like?

Comment: i have: /js/file.js and /css/versionx.css